# When I click the render button it starts not responding, what should I do?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to do a  small applet that renders a caustic when the details are given. The problem is I want it to go trough 3 panes and in the second pane it should show a little loading bar to show the progress it has done, sadly I never see this loading bar, because when I click my button to start my program it starts to not respond, but when it finished doing all its calculations it starts responding again and it shows me my image. I tried introducing a time delay but it didn't help. What should I do so that it doesn't stop responding? If you need any help understanding the code please tell me.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from math import *
from colour import *
import time

ps1 = 1
breite1 = 150
hoehe1 = 150
s1 = 0.01
r1 = int(hoehe1/2-5)
matrix=[]

def Pixel(p,frb):
        s0,t0=int((breite1)/2),int((hoehe1)/2)
        x,y=p[0],p[1]
        s,t=s0+x,t0-y
        return canvas.create_rectangle(s-0.5*ps1, t-0.5*ps1, s+0.5*ps1, t+0.5*ps1, fill=frb, outline=frb)

def Runden(z,n):
        if z>=0:
            return int(z/n+0.5)*n
        else:
            return -int(-z/n+0.5)*n

def Strecke_Matrix(a,b):
        s0,t0=int((breite1)/2),int((hoehe1)/2)
        x0,y0=Runden(a[0],ps1),Runden(a[1],ps1)
        x1,y1=Runden(b[0],ps1),Runden(b[1],ps1)
        if x0==x1:
            ya,yb=min(y0,y1), max(y0,y1)
            y=ya
            while y<=yb:
                l,k=int((x0+s0)/ps1),int((t0-y)/ps1)
                if 0<=k<=len(matrix)-1 and 0<=l<=len(matrix[0])-1:
                    matrix[k][l]+=1
                y+=ps1
        else:
            if x0<x1:
                xa,xb=x0,x1
                ya,yb=y0,y1
            else:
                xa,xb=x1,x0
                ya,yb=y1,y0
            m=(yb-ya)/(xb-xa)
            if abs(m)<=1:
                x=xa
                while x<=xb:
                    y=Runden(m*(x-xa)+ya,ps1)
                    l,k=int((x+s0)/ps1),int((t0-y)/ps1)
                    if 0<=k<=len(matrix)-1 and 0<=l<=len(matrix[0])-1:
                        matrix[k][l]+=1
                    x+=ps1
            else:
                if yb-ya>0:
                    xna,yna=ya,xa
                    xnb,ynb=yb,xb
                else:
                    xna,yna=yb,xb
                    xnb,ynb=ya,xa
                mn=(ynb-yna)/(xnb-xna)
                x=xna
                while x<=xnb:
                    y=Runden(mn*(x-xna)+yna,ps1)
                    xtemp,ytemp=y,x
                    l,k=int((xtemp+s0)/ps1),int((t0-ytemp)/ps1)
                    if 0<=k<=len(matrix)-1 and 0<=l<=len(matrix[0])-1:
                        matrix[k][l]+=1
                    x+=ps1
            return matrix

def PointLight_Matrix(s, r, n):
    w = -1*pi
    while w < pi:
           a = 0
           while a <=  n:
                  p0 = [cos(a*w)*r, sin(a*w)*r]
                  p1 = [cos((a+1)*w)*r, sin((a+1)*w)*r]
                  Strecke_Matrix(p0,p1)
                  a = a + 1
                  time.sleep(0.02)
           w = w + s
    r2 = 0
    for x in matrix:
           for z in x:
                  if z > r2:
                         r2 = z
    return r2

def Matrix1(s, r, n):
    w = -0.5*pi
    while w < 0.5*pi:
        a = 0
        while a <= n:
            p0 = [cos(-a*pi + (2*a+1)*w)*r, sin(-a*pi + (2*a+1)*w)*r]
            p1 = [cos(-(a + 1)*pi + (2*(a + 1)+1)*w)*r, sin(-(a + 1)*pi + (2*(a +1)+1)*w)*r]
            Strecke_Matrix(p0,p1)
            a = a+1
            time.sleep(0.02)
        w = w + s
    r2 = 0
    for x in matrix:
           for z in x:
                  if z > r2:
                         r2 = z
    return r2

##def maxi(matrix):
##        r2 = 0
##        for x in matrix:
##            for z in x:
##                if z > r2:
##                    r2 = z
##        return r2


def render():
              p2.forget(f1)
              p2.add(f2)
              s0,t0=int((breite1)/2),int((hoehe1)/2)
              t1 = str(typ.get())
              n1 = int(n.get())
              g1 = str(g.get())
              b1 = int(b.get())
              if t1 == "Parallel Light":
                  r2 = Matrix1(s1, r1, n1)
              else:
                  r2 = PointLight_Matrix(s1, r1, n1)
              farbe = Color(g1)
              c = 0
              q = 0
              p = 100/(len(matrix))
              u = int((q*10)/10)
              p9["maximum"] = p
              for x in matrix:
                  z = 0
                  p9["value"] = u
                  for a in x:
                      farbe.luminance = min(1,(a/r2)*b1)
                      x, y = z*ps1-s0 , t0 - c*ps1
                      Pixel([x, y],farbe)
                      z += 1
                  q += p
                  c += 1
              p2.forget(f2)
              p2.add(f3)


hor=int((breite1)/ps1)
ver=int((hoehe1)/ps1)
matrix=[]
for i in range(ver):
    zeile=[]
    for j in range(hor):
        zeile.append(0)
    matrix.append(zeile)


root = Tk()
root.title("App")


mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

p2 = ttk.Panedwindow(root, orient="horizontal")
f1 = ttk.Labelframe(p2, text="Settings", height = 150, width = 300)
f2 = ttk.Labelframe(p2, text="Rendering…", height = 150, width = 300)
f3 = ttk.Labelframe(p2, text="Caustic", height = 200, width = 200)
p2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
p2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
p2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
p2.add(f1)


canvas = Canvas(f3, height=hoehe1, width=breite1)
canvas.grid(column=6, row=1, rowspan = 20, padx=10, pady=5)


typ = StringVar()
n = StringVar()
g = StringVar()
b = StringVar()

è = ttk.Label(f1, text="Warning! The higher the number of reflections the longer it will take")
è.grid(column = 1, row = 1, columnspan=4)

type_ = ttk.Combobox(f1, textvariable=typ, state="readonly")
type_.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
type_['values'] = ('Point Light', 'Parallel Light')
type_.current(0)
ttk.Label(f1, text="Type of Light:").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)

q = ttk.Combobox(f1, textvariable=n)
q.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
q['values'] = (1,2,3,4,5)
q.current(0)
ttk.Label(f1, text="Number of reflections:").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)

g_entry = ttk.Entry(f1, width=7, textvariable=g)
g_entry.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Label(f1, text="Color of the Image:").grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W)

s = ttk.Combobox(f1, textvariable=b, state="readonly")
s.grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=(W, E))
s['values'] = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
s.current(0)
ttk.Label(f1, text="Brightness:").grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=W)

p9 = ttk.Progressbar(f2, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode='determinate')
p9.grid(column=6, row=21,padx=5, pady=30)

b3 = ttk.Button(f1, text="Render", command=render)
b3.grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=W)
type_.focus()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First, try using threads [find more here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) Second I see a non-ascii character as a variable you might want to change that, though it shouldn't be whats wrong with your program.

Comment: tkinter can run two things at the same time: your long-running function and tkinter mainloop which gets mouse/keyboard events and updates widgets. You have to use threads. But tkinter isn't threadsave so thread shouldn't update GUI. It has to send information to main thread (ie. using queue) and main thread has to updates GUI.

Comment: @PrestonHager How should I approach it? I never used threads in python. I read the link but I don't really know how to apply it to my code

Comment: Try the new stackoverflow documentation, [here,](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/544/multithreading#t=201610210223182609812) or this article [on threading in python.](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/)

Comment: @PrestonHager okay I implemented everything, why does my program run faster when i move my mouse, also now my progress bar just get's skipped why could that be?

Comment: I had this problem earlier with one of my programs, the reason was because of tkinter's main loop function. I don't remember how I fixed it though. Sorry, I can't help here.